Issues opening projects after downloading in QField

I'm currently facing some issues with our locally deployed QFieldCloud instance and could really use your insights.
While project uploads and downloads are working fine in QGIS, both the Android and Windows versions of QField are displaying the following error msg log, when trying to open after downloading projects in the QField app from the Locally deployed QFieldCloud.
Project file read error in file c:/users/bizit/appdata/roaming/opengis.ch/qfield/cloud_projects/admin/5a536cbb-a423-4835-845f-85594bcdbe34/gis4_cloud_qfield.qgs: premature end of document at line 1, column 0

Error opening zip archive: 'c:/users/bizit/appdata/roaming/opengis.ch/qfield/cloud_projects/admin/5a536cbb-a423-4835-845f-85594bcdbe34/gis4_cloud_qfield_attachments.zip' (error code: 19)

Failed to remove temporary file gis4_cloud_qfield_attachments.zip
Failed to remove temporary file gis4_cloud_qfield.qgs
Failed to remove temporary file data.gpkg

Has anyone encountered similar issues or have suggestions for resolving these errors?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I've deployed QFieldCloud on local server and am able to upload projects from QGIS to the locally deployed QFieldCloud instance successfully. However, when trying to open projects from the QField Android and Windows apps after download of the projects to the local storage is completed, I'm getting the above errors.
